# Is there a good jQuery (Javascript) library to do fast VIDEO (not image) zooming/panning? (target: iPhone through PhoneGap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html

I have a video and I would like to pan/zoom (as it is streaming or playing) on HTML page. The target is to do this on iPhone under PhoneGap. So, a jQuery plugin/example of how to achieve that would be great. The video is a stream that might come through HTML5 (but NOT through Flash Player).

Is this doable? Sample code/plugin? The goal is to do it dynamically so that I can dynamically send new pan location and it will adjust the view of the video accordingly.

Thanks!

Comment: `$("#videoElement").attr('width',desired_width);`? lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jplayer.org/

try this